# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook 2010 Reference in VS 2012 Using .Net 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, outlook, outlook-2010

I was tying to add a `Reference` to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` Namespace in to my web project i'm using .Net 2.0 And visual studio 2012

*Question*

Which one of the following is the one i should choose to work with `Outlook 2010`

**I tried to google this and i couldn't find any thing**

[image]

Comment: Office 2010 is v14. You should reference from the .Net tab..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've chosen wrong tab in Reference Manager. Choose this tab:
[image]

Then find `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` library. If you have multiple choice, then look at `File Version` info - there's a version of Office you can work with: 12.* - 2007, 14.* - 2010, 15.* - 2012.

The best choice is 14.* but the others will mostly work too.
I also need to worry you that Microsoft suggests not to use interop on server side ([link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757))

Answer (score 10):

Or here is GAC path

C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook\14.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll

you can browse manually to folder

C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook\14.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\

and consequently choose Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll